# Unexpected token while adding a type to "value"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
 const count= data.reduce((s:any, {(value:any)}) => s + value, 0);
```

i am trying to add a new type to "value" , it shows unexxected token, i am new to type script please help

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. There shouldn't be any `()` around `value: any` part.
2. You can't provide the type of a destructured parameter inline like that, because it conflicts with the renaming feature of destructuring syntax. `{value: any}` means "take the value of `value` and put it in the variable/parameter called `any`.

To give the type to a destructuring pattern, you type the pattern as a whole:

```typescript
// The destructured parameter −−−−−−vvvvv
const count = data.reduce((s: any, {value}: {value: any}) => s + value, 0);
// The type for the object −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd7CsqAueUB2AngNoC6A3AFAUD018AKgBYKgDOyMArmMp3MPAAOsKAFsUIGPEBIRLLkA3RYopgA9nnbw1nPKgC8aDFAB0-biAAUF1jnwEANPADe8qBE4gAvjhduPtwk8ASng9AD54VngAanhXdxBHAAYgyloGZnhkAkEEADNVKWRM1QAjACtwVDka2rkAPUam5uagA)

---

In general, the `any` type annotation isn't best practice. You haven't shown what `data` is, but in most cases, you shouldn't have to put type annotations on the callback's parameters at all. For example, let's assume `data` is `{value: number;}[]` — an array of objects that have a `value` property that's a number. Given that type for `data`, TypeScript doesn't need any type annotations on that `reduce` call at all:

```typescript
const count = data.reduce((s, {value}) => s + value, 0);
```

TypeScript knows from the `0` at the end and the definition of `data` that both `s` and `value` will be numbers, and that the result will be a number.

---

In a comment you've asked how you'd do this with `forEach` where you also want the index. Again, you probably don't need to specify the types, and you certainly don't need to specify the type of `index` since TypeScript knows what type it will be in a `forEach` callback. But if you did, since `index` isn't destructured, you just specify its type inline:

```typescript
// If TypeScript knwos the type of `this.data`, you DON'T NEED THESE TYPES
this.data.forEach(({value, text, data}: {value: typeOfValue; text: typeOfText; data: typeOfData}, index: number) => {
// Types −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
    // ....
}
```

Comment: How do i destruct if there is more than 1 param like this.data.forEach(({value, text, data}, index) => {

Comment: @Tej - ("destructure") Usually, again, you shouldn't have to specify those types. If TypeScript knows the type of `this.data`, it knows the types of those destructured parameters. But if you *did*, you'd do it just like the above, but with more properties in the type: `this.data.forEach(({value, text, color}: {value: typeOfValue; text: typeOfText; color: typeOfColor; }) => { /*...*/ })`. (But `forEach` isn't really best practice anymore unless you're passing a predefined function to it. Use `for-of` instead: `for (const {value, text, color} of this.data) { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: Great answer T.J. - Thanks for making SO a better place.

Comment: how do i accomodate "index" in for loop

Comment: @Tej - If you need an index, I reverse myself: `forEach` is great for that. :-D And sorry, I see you did have `index` above! You do have an alternative, which is `for (const [index, {value, text, color}] of this.data.entries())` but while I like the semantics, it involves a lot of temporary objects. But they're temporary objects that can be thoroughly optimized...hmm...I feel an optimization test coming on. :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am trying to figure out a way to include index, as i cannot proceed without index value

Comment: @Tej - Right, see my reply above. `forEach` is a good option when you need the index. I also gave you another one which (for me) probably isn't as good.

Comment: in the answer you mentioned.this.data.forEach(({value, text, color}: {value: typeOfValue; text: typeOfText; color: typeOfColor; }) => { /*...*/ }), where can i add index

Comment: @Tej - You don't need to specify the type of `index`, TypeScript knows what the type is. But I've added to the end of the answer for other situations where maybe you would.